# On Google Sheets how to associate a value between two sheets based on the common id match?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

On Google Sheets I have a spreadsheet with a first Sheet containing two columns that have `id` and `price` like this

| id | price |
| --- | --- |
| 000050009 | 1 |
| 934737483 | 3 |

And then I have a second Sheet with columns containing `id` and `title` like this

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 934737483 | Title alpha |
| 123456789 | Title beta! |

How to associate the `title` contained only in second Sheet, into a new column of the first Sheet based on `id` Match?

Comment: `vlookup` should do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Sheet2:

[image]

#### Formula:

```
=arrayformula(ifna(vlookup(A2:A, Sheet2!A2:B, 2, false), ""))
```

[image]

Comment: To let this work I had to change on "File/Spreadsheet settings"  the `Locale` to United States!

Comment: or you can change the delimiters to `;` instead of  `,` if you are on a country that uses them.